# MySql Select rows where value IN comma-delimited column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1,2,3)
```

but in place of 1,2,3 I want to use a column from another table that contains a comma-delimited list just like "1,2,3" above.

I have tried to do this:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.eating_area SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM table_areas a 
WHERE a.eating_area_id IN (
  SELECT
    o.eating_area_ids 
  FROM table_offers o WHERE o.rid=1
)
```

however this only returns the value associated with 1, and not 2 or 3. Can this be done or is there another way to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
WHERE IF(FIND_IN_SET(column,(SELECT "1,2,3" FROM otherTable WHERE 1))>=1,1,0) 
-- FIND_IN_SET will return the position.
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but... i think it could work. 
Source: [Find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Thanks Joseadrian, I just figured that out for myself right now. The FIND_IN_SET that is.